# Differentiating powers of e where the power is an exponential function like $e^{a^x}$ when $a$ is a constant

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Using the fact that $e = \lim_{h \to \infty} (1+h)^{1/h}$, you can answer $\frac{d}{dx} e^{p(x)}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial using the variable x. However, I have troubles finding the derivative of $e^{p(x)}$ where “something” is a exponential function. Is there a way/formula (or multiple formulae) finding the derivative of such functions? I’ll be glad if you include the proof of such ways.

Comment: Use the chain rule. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{f(x)}\right)=e^{f(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$

Comment: Can you give examples of  “logarithmic function?” Polynomial has a standard meaning, but not sure about “logarithmic” in this context.

Comment: logarithmic functions are like $f(x) = a^x$ where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: @a10yearold wouldn't that be an *exponential* function, not a logarithmic one?

Comment: Oh, the biggest mistake in my life! I just will edit the question.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age "You must be at least 13 years old to access or use the Network or Services, including without limitation to complete a Stack Overflow account registration. By accessing or using the Services or the Network in any manner, you represent and warrant that you are at least 13 years of age. If you are under 13 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for any reason, access or use the Services or Network in any manner...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful way for this kind of problem is logarithmic differentiation.

$$y=e^{a^{f(x)}} \implies \log(y)=a^{f(x)}=e^{f(x)\log(a)}\implies\frac {y'}y=e^{f(x)\log(a)}\log(a) f'(x)$$